# How to utilize recursive functions to help rank matrix rows - R

Tags: r, recursion, matrix

I would like some advice as to how best solve this puzzle.  I have got some of the way to solving it using manually written long-hand code.   I feel as if I need to utilize recursive functions, but I am still not very good at using them.   I hope this question is not too long, I'm trying to be as succinct as possible whilst giving enough information.  Sorry if it's too long - though hopefully somebody finds it of interest.

I have a matrix `mat1`

```
#   A B C D E F G
# A 0 2 1 1 0 1 1
# B 0 0 0 1 2 2 1
# C 1 2 0 0 0 2 1
# D 1 1 2 0 1 2 1
# E 2 0 2 1 0 2 1
# F 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
# G 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

This represents the results of contests between individuals in rows and columns.  Numbers refer to how often the individual in the row 'won' against the individual in the column.

I wish to rank individuals A-G from 1-7 using the following criteria:

- number of wins against all others (most wins should be ranked 1, least wins 7, 2nd most wins 2, etc.)
- if number of wins are tied, then ranks should be based on the number of wins obtained when considering contests only between those individuals with the same number of wins.
- if individuals still have a tied number of wins, then ranks should be applied randomly.

I realize that this is not a very good ranking system, but that's not the issue here. According to the above scheme, ranks should be the following:

- **1** - D or E - D & E have joint highest overall wins (8), and equal wins also in contests between them.
- **2** - E or D - pick randomly D or E for rank 1 and rank 2
- **3** - A or C - tied with A,B,C,G for overall 6 wins, both have 4 wins in contents with ABCG
- **4** - C or A - considering contests between C&A both have 1 win, so randomly pick for rank3 and rank4
- **5** - G - tied with A,B,C,G for overall 6 wins, has 3 wins in contests between A,B,C,G
- **6** - B - tied with A,B,C,G for overall 6 wins, but only has 1 win in contests between A,B,C,G
- **7** - F - has the fewest wins of all in the overall win matrix

## What I have tried:

```
storeresults <- vector("list") #use this to store results of the following
```

**Step 1:** Use `winsfun` function (see below) to identify number of wins of each individual & whether wins are unique (as noted by dupes column):

```
w1 <- winsfun(mat1)
storeresults[[1]] <- w1  #store results
```

`w1` Only "F" has a unique number of wins and so can be ranked (7th) in the first instance:

```
#  wins ranks dupes
#A    6   4.5  TRUE
#B    6   4.5  TRUE
#C    6   4.5  TRUE
#D    8   1.5  TRUE
#E    8   1.5  TRUE
#F    2   7.0 FALSE
#G    6   4.5  TRUE
```

**Step 2:** For individuals with non-unique wins (i.e. duplicated ranks) subset them into matrices considering only contests against others with the same number of wins, and determine new ranks if possible.

```
allSame(w1[,3]) #FALSE - this says that not all wins/ranks are unique so need to subset

s2 <- subsetties(w1)  #this just splits the data into groups by number of wins (see below)

w2 <- lapply(s2, winsfun, m=mat1)
storeresults[[2]] <- w2 # store results
```

`w2` As can be seen, those individuals with 8 wins (the most of anyone) from Step1 ("D" and "E") each have one win versus each other. They cannot be teased apart, so will be ranked 1 and 2 randomly.   Those individuals with 6 wins (A, B, C, G) have different number of wins when only considering contests between each other.  "B" and "G" can be ranked 6th overall and 5th overall respectively.  We need to reconsider "A" and "C" in contests against only each other:

```
$`6`
  wins ranks dupes
A    4   1.5  TRUE
B    1   4.0 FALSE
C    4   1.5  TRUE
G    3   3.0 FALSE

$`8`
  wins ranks dupes
D    1   1.5  TRUE
E    1   1.5  TRUE
```

**Step 3:**  Repeat Step 2 where required

```
 allSame(w2[[1]][,3])  #FALSE - need to subset again as not everyone has same number of wins
    allSame(w2[[2]][,3])  #TRUE  - no more action required
    
    s3 <- subsetties(w2[[1]])
    
w3 <- winsfun(s3[[1]], m=mat1)
storeresults[[3]] <- w3 #store results
```

`w3` When considering "A" and "C" together, they have one win each, so should now be ranked randomly in 2nd and 3rd place. They cannot be teased apart.

```
  wins ranks dupes
A    1   1.5  TRUE
C    1   1.5  TRUE

allSame(w3[,3])  #TRUE - no more action required - both have same number of wins
```

**Step 4** Processing Stored Results

```
storeresults  
# I can manually work out ranks from this, but have yet to work out how to do it in R
```

**Below are the functions used in the above:**

**Function to calculate wins and ranks of subsetted matrices**

```
winsfun <- function(m, out=NULL){

if (is.null(out)==F){
m1 <- m[rownames(out),rownames(out)]
wins <- apply(m1, 1, sum)
ranks <- rank(-wins)
dupes <- duplicated(wins)| duplicated(wins, fromLast = T)
df <- data.frame(wins, ranks,dupes)
return(df)
}

else
wins <- apply(m, 1, sum)
ranks <- rank(-wins)
dupes <- duplicated(wins)| duplicated(wins, fromLast = T)
df <- data.frame(wins, ranks,dupes)
return(df)
}
```

**Function to subset those rows with duplicated ranks**

```
 subsetties <- function(df){
        df1 <- df[df[,3]==T,]
        df1.sp <- split(df1, df1$wins)
        return(df1.sp)
    }
```

**Function to test if all elements of vector are identical**

```
allSame <- function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1
```

**Code to recreate above matrix:**

```
structure(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
    "E", "F", "G")))
```

I hope this question is clear.    I am trying to work out how to perform this algorithm iteratively.  I am not too sure how to achieve this, but hopefully by writing this out long-hand and providing the functions I have been using, it may be obvious to somebody.   One extra thing is that it's best to have the proposed solution be generally applicable (i.e. to matrices of different sizes).

Comment: Why not use `rowSums` and `rank` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
calc_gain<-function(mat=mat1){
    if(nrow(mat)==1) {
        return(row.names(mat))
    } else {
        classement<-sort(rowSums(mat),decreasing=T)
        diffgains<-diff(classement)
        if (all(diffgains!=0)){
            return(names(classement))
        } else {
            if (all(diffgains==0)){
                return(sample(names(classement)))
            } else {
                parex<-split(classement,factor(classement,levels=unique(classement)))
                class_parex<-lapply(parex,function(vect){calc_gain(mat[names(vect),names(vect),drop=F])})
                return(unlist(class_parex))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the function does :

- if there is only one element, it returns the name of it (only "player" there is)
- else, it calculates the scores.

  - If there is no tie, it returns the "players" in the order first to last
  - else, - if all "players" have the same score, it randomly gives an order.

    - else, it splits the ordered list according to the scores and apply the function (that is the recursive part) on the subsets of "players" with tied scores.

Comment: This is fabulous - thank you.   I've checked it with several matrices of different sizes, and so far it seems to generalize very well.  I will need to spend a bit of time working out a bit more exactly how it's doing what it's doing and might have a follow-up comment.   Regardless, thank you very much.

Comment: @jalapic, you're welcome, I'm glad if it helps. The first part (two first points actually) of the function makes sure it ends at some point and the last part does the trick... Don't hesitate to aks, should you have questions.

Comment: thanks again- I do see how it's doing it after studying it in more detail - it's the use of `diff` that really makes it elegant. Though I think constructing recursive functions requires a slightly different mindset than I'm used to.   I only have one minor question - I'm not too sure why `drop=F` is necessary?

Comment: It makes sure that everything goes well when there is only one element left (e.g. for F in mat1) : we need to get the row.names so mat[one_element,one_element] needs to remain a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

Step0:

```
> split(rownames(m), -rowSums( m ) )
$`-8`
[1] "D" "E"

$`-6`
[1] "A" "B" "C" "G"

$`-2`
[1] "F"
```

Step1:

```
m <-  m[ order( -rowSums(m) ), ])  # order within overall wins
  A B C D E F G
D 1 1 2 0 1 2 1
E 2 0 2 1 0 2 1
A 0 2 1 1 0 1 1
B 0 0 0 1 2 2 1
C 1 2 0 0 0 2 1
G 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
F 1 0 0 0 0 0 1

> rowSums( m )
D E A B C G F 
8 8 6 6 6 6 2
```

Step2: Order within group that has 4 wins

```
> mred <- m[c("A","B","C","G"), c("A","B","C","G") ]
> mred
  A B C G
A 0 2 1 1
B 0 0 0 1
C 1 2 0 1
G 1 1 1 0
> rowSums(mred)
A B C G 
4 1 4 3 

> rownames(mred)[order(-rowSums(mred))]
[1] "A" "C" "G" "B"
```